# oracle package trouble

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I'm very new to oracle packages and was wondering if someone could explain why this won't compile/execute.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE login_pkg IS
 FUNCTION login_ck_pf 
  (p_user IN VARCHAR2,
   p_pass IN VARCHAR2)
   RETURN CHAR;
END;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY login_pkg IS
 FUNCTION login_ck_pf 
  (p_user IN VARCHAR2,
   p_pass IN VARCHAR2)
   RETURN CHAR
  IS
   lv_ck_txt CHAR(1) := 'N';
   lv_id_num NUMBER(5);
 BEGIN
   SELECT idShopper
    INTO lv_id_num
    FROM bb_shopper
    WHERE username = p_user
     AND password = p_pass;
   IF SQL%FOUND THEN
     lv_ck_txt := 'Y';
     lv_id_num := lv_id_num;
   END IF;
   RETURN lv_ck_txt;
 EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Invalid Login');
   lv_ck_txt := 'N';
   return lv_ck_txt;
 END;
END;
/
show errors;

execute login_pkg.login_ck_pf('gma1', 'goofy');
```

Thank you for your help so far, I have it compiling now I just need to figure out how to call it. If the row is found I want to return a Y and if it isn't found I want to return N.

```
PACKAGE login_pkg compiled
PACKAGE BODY login_pkg compiled
No Errors.

Error starting at line 35 in command:
execute login_pkg.login_ck_pf('gma1', 'goofy')
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00221: 'LOGIN_CK_PF' is not a procedure or is undefined
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Comment: Once you have a got an answer please do not edit your post to ask a new question.  SO is a Q&A site not a forum.  It's one question per thread and (ideally) one answer per question.  So just ask a new question (linking to the old one if it's appropriate).  Editing your question to chnage its meaning confuses people and pollutes the thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since login_ck_pf is a function and not a procedure, you're going to need to provide a variable to assign the return value:

```
DECLARE
    v_ret CHAR(1);
BEGIN
    v_ret := login_pkg.login_ck_pf('gma1','goofy');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_ret);
END;
/
```

Alternatively, you could do this:

```
SELECT login_pkg.login_ck_pf('gma1','goofy') FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to create the package specification first, then you can compile your body (implementation):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE login_pkg IS

 FUNCTION login_ck_pf 
  (p_user IN VARCHAR2,
   p_pass IN VARCHAR2)
   RETURN CHAR;

END;
/
```

The package specification is where you define the signatures (interface, api) of the procedures, functions, constants, types, etc which you wish to expose for use. The package body has the implementation of these definitions. A specification can exist without a body, but a body cannot exist without a specification. Everything defined in the specification must be implemented in the body. You may define additional procedures in the body without putting them in the specification, and these then act as "private" procedures for use within the body and not available for external use.

I guess while we're at it there are couple of other things in the body. I don't see lv_id_num or pv_id_num being used anywhere. If a row is not found, then will the block of code with "if sql%found" even be hit or will you go straight to the exception handler? Do you want to return a value your 'N' if the exception handler is invoked? I know you're just hacking around at this point, so just some ideas.

Comment: The output shows that the package has run and compiled.  The problem is clearly as @DanA says: LOGIN_CK_PF is defined as a function but the OP is attempting to call it as though it were a procedure.

Comment: @APC This response was to the original version of the question where the package did not compile because there was no spec.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise the OP had edited their question.  Please make a trivial edit to your answer so I can un-ding you.